# A step in a proof that $M, N\unlhd G$ implies $MN\unlhd G$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

*This is an easy question for me to verify, I suppose, but, for whatever reason, I'm having a crisis of confidence.*

This is a [proof-verification](/questions/tagged/proof-verification) question.

*The bit I'm unsure of is highlighted in bold text.*

### The Question:

> Suppose $G$ is a group with $M,N\unlhd G$. Show that $MN\unlhd G$.

### My Proof:

Since $M,N\unlhd G$, we have $e\in M\cap N$. Hence $e=ee\in MN$, so $MN\neq \emptyset$.

Let $g,h\in MN$. Then $g=mn$ and $h=m'n'$ for some $m,m'\in M$, $n,n'\in N$. Consider

$$\begin{align}
gh^{-1}&=(mn)(m'n')^{-1}\\
&=(mn)(n'^{-1}m'^{-1}) \\
&=m(nn'^{-1})m'^{-1}.
\end{align}$$

**We may write $m=\mu m'$ for some $\mu\in M$ since $M$ is a group and right multiplication of an element of a group is a bijection on that group.** Hence

$$gh^{-1}=\mu(m'(nn'^{-1})m'^{-1}),$$

but $m'(nn'^{-1})m'^{-1}\in N$ since $N\unlhd G$. Thus $gh^{-1}\in MN$.

Hence $MN\le G$ by the one-step subgroup test.

Now let $mn\in MN$ and $g\in G$. Then

$$g^{-1}mng=(g^{-1}mg)(g^{-1}Ng),$$

where $g^{-1}mg\in M$ as $M\unlhd G$ and $g^{-1}ng\in N$ as $N\unlhd G$. Hence $g^{-1}mng\in MN$.

Thus $MN\unlhd G$.  $\square$

---

*Why am I unsure?*

I don't know. What says that $\mu\in M$? I mean: I know it's because of the reason stated above but I feel like I've waved my hands a little bit there.

Please help :)

Comment: $\mu = m(m')^{-1}$ works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can formally justify the step you have a doubt on:

Consider the map

$$\phi_{m'}:M \to M: g\to gm'$$

This map is a bijection (an inverse is easy to construct, while constructing this you will see what $\mu$ actually is - also shown in the comments)

Thus, in particular, the map is surjective and thus for $m \in M$, there exists $\mu \in M$ such that $\mu m' =\phi_{m'}(\mu) = m$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you :)

Comment: But does the highlighted bit make sense or have I sweeped stuff under the carpet?

Comment: I don't follow. The $m'$ is needed on the left hand side of $nn'^{-1}m'^{-1}$ in order for it to be a conjugate, so in $N$.

Comment: I edited my answer! Let me know if anything is unclear :)

Comment: No, that's perfect. Thank you :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)